Sharepoint - LoadQuery method in CSOM does not support the .Skip()
During work on a console app (running on .NET 4.7.2), I'm using CSOM to connect to Sharepoint and then get some data, but I get this error:

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidQueryExpressionException: 'The query expression 'value(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCollection).Where(list => ((list.BaseTemplate == 101) AndAlso (list.Hidden == False))).OrderBy(list => list.Id).Include(new [] {list => list.Title, list => list.RootFolder.Name}).Take(100).Skip(0)' is not supported.'

It looks like the problem is with the query, specifically with .Skip. If I remove skip from the query, the error no longer shows up.
Here is the code:
try
{
   int batchSize = 100;
   int currentBatch = 0;
   bool hasMoreLibraries = true;
   var allDocumentLibraries = new List<List>(); 

   while (hasMoreLibraries)
   {
      var documentLibraries = context.LoadQuery(context.Web.Lists
         .Where(list => list.BaseTemplate == (int)ListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary
                        && list.Hidden == false)                        
         .OrderBy(list => list.Id)
         .Include(list => list.Title, list => list.RootFolder.Name)
         .Take(batchSize)
         .Skip(currentBatch * batchSize)
         );

      context.ExecuteQuery();
      allDocumentLibraries.AddRange(documentLibraries);

      if (documentLibraries.Count() < batchSize)
      {
          hasMoreLibraries = false;
      }
      
      foreach (var library in documentLibraries)
      {
          // do smt
      }

      currentBatch++;
   }

   return allDocumentLibraries;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex);
   return null;
}

Can somebody tell me what is the problem here? Why is .Skip not recognized? What am I doing wrong? Is there a different (better) approach?
Thanks for your answers.
